# MAXMEM macro - Linux Memory Management

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I read Professional Linux Kernel Architechture. They said: *"**MAXMEM** denotes the maximum possible amount of physical RAM that can be directly addressed by the kernel"*

In kernel source

```
#define MAXMEM  (VMALLOC_END - PAGE_OFFSET - __VMALLOC_RESERVE)
```

As I know, `__VMALLOC_RESERVE` is address space from `VMALLOC_START` to the end of Linear Address Space.

Why we calculate `MAXMEM` like that? Why `MAXMEM` is not 896MB?